# how to delete multiple files according to the content in ubuntu

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu

I want to delete all the files which only contains one line in it. To list the number of lines  in each file is `wc -l *txt`. I only know how to use `rm` to delete files with specific names but not the line of content.

Can anyone help? Many thanks!

Comment: Do you want to delete the line from the file or delete the file itself?

Comment: @hek2mgl I mean to delete the file itself, thanks!

Comment: From the current directory? Or recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any answer to this question will not have anything to do with this being on ubuntu. You can do this using bash, on Linux/*nix/bsd, and including cygwin (on Windows) or on Mac terminal.

```
for i in `ls`; do n1=$(wc $i | awk '{print $1}'); if [ $n1 -eq 1 ]; then rm $i; fi; done
```

Answer (score 2):

you can combine `wc` and `awk` into an oneliner

```
 wc -l *.txt|awk '$1==1{print "rm "$2}'
```

this will print the `rm xxx.txt` for you. if you want to execute it, just pipe the output to `sh`

example:

```
kent$  wc -l *.txt                           
 1 a.txt
 1 b.txt
 2 c.txt
 2 d.txt
 1 e.txt
 7 total

kent$  wc -l *.txt|awk '$1==1{print "rm "$2}'
rm a.txt
rm b.txt
rm e.txt

kent$  wc -l *.txt|awk '$1==1{print "rm "$2}'|sh

kent$  l
total 8.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 4 Mar  4 16:41 c.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 4 Mar  4 16:41 d.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
for i in `ls -1 $dir`
do
   if [ `wc -l $i` -eq 1 ]; then
        rm $i
   fi
done
```